# evaluates to be false vs evaluates to false

Tags: grammaticality

> "The guard condition evaluates to be false"

vs

> "The guard condition evaluates to false"

Which one is grammatical?

Comment: Can you give me context, I am having trouble understanding either one.

Comment: @brentwpeterson The context is computer programming.  Think of a "guard condition" as some set of safety checks that the computer must do before proceeding with an operation.  In this case, "evaluates to false" is likely intended as a way of saying "the safety check failed, so an action appropriate for that failure must be taken".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Programmers say ***evaluates to X***.  They generally do not say ****evaluates to be X***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=evaluates+to+false,evaluates+to+be+false&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1;,evaluates%20to%20false;,c0)

This is a technical phrase used by programmers, and in this phrase *to* is a preposition and not an infinitive marker, so inserting *be* would be inappropriate.

Comment: That being said, it's pretty easy to make sense of the latter. I also feel like there should be a sentence where "evaluates to be" would be appropriate, but can't come up with anything.

Comment: Here's a sentence which uses both **evaluates to** and **evaluates to be**- _" A constraint that evaluates to true when the value defined by the dynamic operand evaluates to be within the specified range."_ Here "evaluates to be" is used as an interval indicator.

Comment: @snailplane I'm not sure what you mean here. It's not that I disagree with your answer, in fact, I'm all for it. What I intend to show is that **evaluates to be** fits better when used as an interval marker, rather than being used as **a condition evaluates to be true/false**.

Comment: @ManishGiri That sentence is rather snakey all together.  I think the point in defending a usage pattern isn't to find a sentence on the Internet where someone has used it, but to find a case where it is used to good effect in an overall communicative way.  If you are painted into a linguistic corner and it's the only way to make something feel like it works if you can only change one word, being painted into the corner is the problem, and shouldn't be used to justify the construction.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sound like a natural speaker then neither is correct. Most people would use, 'The guard condition is false'. Except in situations where the evaluation itself is under question; which even in programming is uncommon.

If you are writing a compiler and speaking to someone about a situation where a line should be evaluated a certain way but, for whatever reason, it isn't then you would be careful about the distinction between the evaluation of the line and the result itself. In that case, either of your examples is very common.

Otherwise, it is assumed that the evaluation of the line itself is always correct and the distinction which your versions make between what is written and what is calculated need not be made.

Comment: Please see my answer; you really shouldn't say "the guard condition is false" unless you've literally written `if (false)` or similar.  Even if you are going to be lax about it, you still must be precise about the distinction of whether the evaluative result itself is actually false, or if the condition merely is not "satisfied".

Comment: You've already made that distinction by including the word 'condition'. Even that is only needed when the condition is missing a !, IMHO.

Comment: You run out of descriptions if you are too lax; programming doesn't favor ambiguity. With `if (foo - bar)`, I might point at the code and say *"what is the condition here?"* Does it depend if we are in a debugger with foo and bar at 1 at this point? How much are we losing if we condense it to say "the condition is false?" I'd allow the condition is "foo - bar", but prefer "conditional expression" and saying "conditions" are only satisfied or not. With values I'd say the condition *evaluated* to 0...and perhaps I'd say it evaluated to a "logically false value"; but not "evaluated to false".

Comment: I don't deny that their are occasions where you might use this. I just don't think it is very often that I would phrase it like that.

Comment: Well I want to re-make the point that we agree in wanting to say that "a condition" should be a binary thing linguistically; it is "met" or "satisfied" or "true" or it is not. Unfortunately we can't have our cake and eat it too. If we want to use the shorthand of saying that "condition" can be the convenient name we use for the *expression defining the condition* -OR- the evaluative result of it (which is common practice), then we can finesse the issue by using the words "satisfied" and "unsatisfied" to keep from colliding with actual evaluations of true/false. Keep it under consideration. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> "The guard condition evaluates to false."

That's the more correct phrasing in the two choices given; and the grammar explanation has already been provided.  But I want to mention that the word choices here enter into fine points of programming semantics.

A guard *condition* is controlled by an *expression* to be evaluated.  For instance, in C++ you might say:

```
if (1 - 1) {
    std::cout << "guard condition satisfied\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "guard condition not satisfied\n";
}
```

`1 - 1` will evaluate to zero.  Although zero isn't the same thing as `false`...for purposes of the `if` statement choosing which branch to take...it will go through to the else branch here.

So you would only be truly correct in saying "the guard condition evaluates to false" if it produced an *actual false value*.  A great deal of the time you are actually more interested in expressing which branch the conditional takes.  In those cases you would just say a *condition* "is" either *satisfied* or *not satisfied*.

I've mentioned this mostly as response to the answer that said you could write "the guard condition is false".  If the *conditional expression* itself actually is *false* ... literally written as `if (false)` ... it's only then you really technically should say "the guard condition is false".

But even under the general usage that assumes you mean there is an evaluation taking place, you should be careful to distinguish whether you actually meant to emphasize that the condition was *"not satisfied"*.  If that is what you meant, it is the safer language to use.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question (except for the first line or two).

Comment: @Drew The question is about whether saying *"the guard condition evaluates to false"* is a correct thing to say.  And this is an answer saying "It's not actually *correct*" either way.  Not only is this *an answer*, it is a sophisticated one--coming from a long background in both English and computer software.  In those domains the correct thing to say is "The guard condition is satisfied."  Conditions are not true or false; conditional expressions are.

Comment: Nonsense. I have a longer background in both, I'm sure. There is nothing wrong with saying that a guard condition (or just a guard) evaluates to X. See [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions)  (for functional programming) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)) (more generally). The evaluation is not necessarily the same kind as that of the guarded expression, but that is *beside the point here (which is a point about grammar)*.

Comment: @Drew Another answer had covered the grammar point already. I merely agreed--and wanted to add the important bit about how the evaluation type is not necessarily the same kind as of the guarded expression...plus give enough distinctions to help model that "the condition is false" (from another answer) is wrong, unless you've literally written `if (false)`. So introducing "conditional expression" was in service of that goal for precision. As for who's been programming longer, [I wouldn't be so sure](http://blog.hostilefork.com/osborne-one-basic-fun-history/), but that is also besides the point.

Comment: I'm sure.  If you started with [Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC), as your link suggests, then you are a relative newbie ;-). And the only correctness that counts here is English correctness. And the question was *Which one is grammatical?* All of your answer past the first two sentences (now your first sentence, after your edit) is off-topic.

Comment: @Drew When you can't actually one-up someone after a bogus posturing that was way more off topic than the answer could ever be, just dig oneself in a deeper hole by being more insulting?  I fail to see the path to success in that.  But either way, I stand by my answer's value in the conversation; which are English usage points as applied to the programming domain--and have tweaked a bit to make the points even more clear.

Comment: Sorry if you took my comments as an insult. My initial comment explained why I voted to close. My followups tried to explain why this is not an answer to the English question, and incidentally to correct the programming content. I linked to programming references that explicitly relate to the use of the term *evaluates to false* wrt guards. And BTW, you are the one who started out by touting your "*sophisticated < answer > -- coming from a long background in both English and computer software.*"

Comment: Your opposition against "the guard condition is false" is misplaced: "false" is an adjective, not a noun, so in case the guard condition is "2+2=5", it is perfectly acceptable to say the guard condition is false. Indeed 2+2=5 is false, though it is not identical to "false". (The question was about "evaluates to" rather than "is", which more properly reflects the fact that determining the status of the condition probably involves such things as taking the current values of variables, but that is another discussion.)

Answer (score 0):

The variant with "to be false" seems grammatically incorrect. The variant with "evaluates to false" would be correct in a programming context (although I would be tempted to typeset it as "evaluates to **false**"), where "**true**" and "**false**" are taken to be names of the two values of the Boolean type.

The phrase "The guard condition evaluates to false" does look slightly wrong from a grammatical point of view, since "false" is an adjective whereas it here designates the value resulting from the evaluation. One might say "evaluates to a false value", but I would personally avoid that; another alternative would be "evaluates to falsity".

Comment: Usage defines correctness. You're far more likely to see "evaluates to false" than something like "evaluates to falsity," so I would argue that in the programming context "false" and "true" are acceptable putative nouns. Or conversely, that we shouldn't get too hung up on parts of speech!

Comment: @Tiercelet: That is exactly my opinion (and this was quite clearly a programming context); I changed "acceptable" to "correct" to avoid suggesting any disapproval.

Answer (score 0):

Think of saying "23rd June" or "23rd of June". What you *should* say is "the 23rd day of June", but we use shorthand versions of these phrases where you miss out the bits that are obvious.

The 'be' is similarly dropped in many cases, especially when something is assigned or otherwise becomes something else, and I'd say is a shorthand itself for the word 'becomes'.

In this case though, the condition is being *compared* to false and so there is no 'becoming', if the guard condition was set then it'd be a different matter, though the 'be' tends to be dropped regardless.

Answer (score 0):

To me the second option (*evaluates to be false*) has always sounded a little silly. But I do I think that if the speaker is imagining some kind of flow in time/future tense involved in the evaluation then it isn't necessarily wrong. It's a slight difference in perception perhaps.